# TypeScript string union type inferences problem in composite types

Tags: typescript

I have the following code which won't compile with TypeScript compiler `3.7.3`

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'banana'

const val = 'apple'

// Works. TS remembers the value of `val`
const fruit: Fruit = val

type Basket = {
    fruit: Fruit
}

const obj = {
    fruit: 'apple' 
}

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fruit'.
// TS probably discarded that `fruit` property has concrete value and treats it as any `string`.
const structuralBasket: Basket = obj

// This works 
const declaredBasket: Basket = {
    fruit: 'apple'
}
```

I need the `obj` to stay as is. What I cannot do and not looking for in the  answer:

- using enums
- declaring `obj` as a `Basket`

Is this a limitation of TypeScript compiler?

If so, is there workaround ? Will this be addressed in the future ?

Comment: The only thing I know of is explicitly telling TS that `fruit` in `obj` *will* be something that's contained in `Fruit` by doing `obj = { fruit: 'apple'  as const }`. I'm not if you can somehow automatically enable this sort of inference in the compiler, though - the fact that you've declared `fruit` to be `'apple'` *now* doesn't mean it can't change later if somebody does `obj.fruit = 'lemon'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you just declare `obj` its gets a wider type then `Fruit` is, so what you got is `{fruit: string}`, what is naturally not assignable to its sub-type. You can add `as const`

```
const obj = {
    fruit: 'apple' 
} as const
```

And such construct will be inferred as `{fruit: 'apple'}`, what is already assignable to `Basket` being its subtype.

You can also create such objects by value constructors. Consider:

```
const makeBasket = (fruit: Fruit): Basket => ({fruit})
const obj = makeBasket('apple'); // Basket object
```